# CCSprite not showing Background Image

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am facing an unknown error since from yesterday. I am creating CCSprites or CCMenuItemImage but it set black background instead of background image. Following is my code, I know its fine because I used it before many times.

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"challenge_screen.plist"];

CCSprite *bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ads.png"];
    [bg setPosition:background.position];

//    [bg setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
    [self addChild:bg z:1000];



    //CGSize windowSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CCMenuItemImage *coinMenuItem = [[CCMenuItemImage alloc] initWithNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"coin.png"]] selectedSprite:nil disabledSprite:nil block:^(id sender)
     {
         NSLog(@"I am Tapped");
     }];
    coinMenuItem.position = ccp(100, 100);
    CCMenu *mainMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:coinMenuItem, nil];
    mainMenu.position = CGPointZero;
    [self addChild:mainMenu];
```

Attached is screenshot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure your plist is defined correctly ? how did you create it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are loading this sprite sheet (`challenge_screen.plist` and the associated texture file, which frequently is `challenge_screen.png` or `challenge_screen.pvr.*`) in a color mode that doesn't have transparency.

First, make sure that the associated texture file shows transparency itself. Maybe something messed with this particular texture.

Once you checked that, if the associated texture is `.PNG.` then you have to set the texture loading format in code like this. You have to set the texture format before loading the texture itself (the texture loads as a side effect of adding the SpriteFrames to the cache).

```
  [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444];
  [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"challenge_screen.plist"];`
  ...
```

You can also try the `kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888` mode if `RGBA444` produces banding with your graphics and if you are good regarding free memory.

On the other hand, if the texture is a `PVR.*`, then the format in which the texture loads is embedded in the file, and setting the texture format in code doesn't make a difference. You will then need to regenerate your sprite sheet using the appropriate format (through *TexturePacker* or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Is your background in the sprite sheet? If so try:

```
CCSprite *bg = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"ads.png"];
```

If it is the menu item and you know the code works, it must be an asset issue.